# SAS/WPS HTTP PROC Basic Authentication

Tags: rest, sas, jira-rest-api, wps

Am trying to get the data from JIRA REST API using WPS. I was using the HTTP PROC to call JIRA rest api.

```
proc http 
method="GET"
url="http://servername:8080/rest/api/2/search?%str(&)fields=project,status%str(&)jql=project=C12395"
webusername="username" 
webpassword="password" 
ct="application/JSON"
out=resp;
run;
```

Am getting error/response code as 400.

```
NOTE: Call to [http://servername:8080/rest/api/2/search?&fields=project,
      status&jql=project=C12395] returned [400]
NOTE: Procedure http step took :
      real time : 0.628
      cpu time  : 0.031
```

Am really not sure what am missing. Same JIRA REST API URL working in JAVA.

Note: WPS version is 3.2

Thanks!
Bharathi

Comment: What version of SAS?

Comment: SAS 9.2 Version

Comment: The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax.  It looks like you may have an extranneous `&` immediately after the `?`.  Perhaps this is throwing it off... perhaps not.  Also try simplifying it for the moment and using single quotes so you can eliminate quoting as a cause for concern:  `'http://servername:8080/rest/api/2/search?fields=project,status&jql=project=C12395'`

Comment: i will try it too :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a api key in jira https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/using-personal-access-tokens-1026032365.html

Then use a api

```
    proc http
    method="get"
    out=jsonfile
    url="<url>";
    headers "Accept"="application/json;charset=UTF-8" "Authorization"="Bearer <api key>";
    run;
```